# Use range_tool in Bokeh with category value

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to create a bar plot with range tool because the x-axis has a lot of categories.

This is a sample code, I try to create bar plot with range tool based on `AccountID` in bokeh but it did not work:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, RangeTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Sample data
AccountID = ['A1233', 'B3453', 'C1213', 'D1241']
Value = [10, 20, 30, 40]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=Account, y=Value))

p = figure(x_range=x, height=400, title="Bar Chart")
p.vbar(x='x', top='y', width=0.9, source=source)

range_tool = figure(height=130, x_range=p.x_range, y_range=(0, max(y)))
range_tool.vbar(x='x', top='y', width=0.9, source=source)

p.y_range.callback = RangeTool(x_range=range_tool.x_range).callback

output_file("bar_chart_with_range_tool.html")

show(p)
```

It will raise an error:
`ValueError: failed to validate RangeTool(id='p2528', ...).x_range: expected either None or a value of type Instance(Range1d), got FactorRange(id='p2430', ...)`

How can I do to create the bar plot like this in Bokeh [Bar plot with range_tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hahMY.png). Please help me.